# All my UIView frames have height and width of 0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a storyboard with a view, but all my UIViews (actually UIViewTable and UIScrollView) appear to have a frame.width and frame.height of 0.

I can clearly see them in the simulator.

```
 - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    // check frame size of tableView
    NSLog(@"Frame width = %f, height = %f", self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);

    // check contentSize of tableView
    NSLog(@"contentSize width = %f, height = %f", self.tableView.contentSize.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);

    // check frame size of scrollView
    NSLog(@"scrollView size - width = %f, height = %f", self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

All these logs show 0 for the height and the width.

Comment: And? Give details of how you created them and constraints.

Comment: have you connected IBOutlet property to the storyboard component?

Comment: try to log the self.scrollview in NSLog. this will show all details.

Comment: Thanks CoolMonster and x4h1d. self.scrollView was null and after connecting the IBOutlet I get the actual height and width.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't name your `tableView` "tableView" and should be the same for scrollView, because of the delegate methods that usually use "tableView" for the local name.